# Find the number of elements in the rest of the array that is greater than the element at each current position

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, count

Let's say I am given a one dimensional array:

> [2, 3, 1, 5, 0, 2]

The goal is to construct another array of the same length where each element denotes the number of elements (not distinct) in the subsequent elements in the array that is bigger than the current number. So the output in my case would be:

> [2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0]

An `O(n^2)` algorithm is pretty straight forward. What could be a more efficient algorithm (in Java preferably) for this?

Comment: I suppose that you can iterate over the array backwards, and then create a new sorted list as you go.  the number you use is just the number of elements after that element in your sorted list.  You can probably turn that into a **O(n*lg(n))** algorithm

Comment: @SamIam the OP says that he need to count in **subsequent** elements, not all. Sorting will destroy the order, thus it will not save subsequences, so i don't think that sorting is a correct solution

Comment: @FalconUA Look at the third element in his example. he mapped that `1` to a `2`, even though the biggest number was right after the `1`

Comment: He is not mapping anything, the third element in his array is just a number of elements in subsequent that is larger than 1, so we have only **2** elements: 5 and 2.

Comment: @FalconUA so how will making a new sorted list prevent him from doing that?

Comment: @SamIam `[2, 3, 1, 5, 0, 2] -> [0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 5]`. If he count the number of elements after that element in the sorted list, he will receive `[3, 1, 4, 0, 5, 2]`, or i didn't correctly understand your solution?

Comment: @FalconUA  The Idea was to make the output array as you go, not to sort the whole array and then figure out what your output is.  So for your first iteratiion, you output array would be `[null, null, null, null ,null, 0]` the new list that you're keeping would just be `[2]`, on the next iteration, your output array would be `[null, null, null, null ,1, 0]` and your sorted list would be `[0, 2]`

Comment: @Samlam thanks for the idea. Yes I think that will work. I will try implementing the algorithm in Java.

Comment: @SamIam On second thought, isn't the worst case run time of your algorithm going to be `O(n^2)` as well ? More precisely: `nlogn + (n - 1)log(n - 1) + (n - 2)log(n - 2) + ... + log1 = O(n^2)`, unless I am missing something.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in O(nlogn) using a [Fenwick tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenwick_tree), a data structure that holds a histogram in a way such that range queries can be done in O(logn) time.

Simply iterate over the elements in reverse order and add them to the histogram.

Python code:

```
def fenwick_new(m):
    """Create empty fenwick tree with space for elements in range 0..m"""
    # tree[i] is sum of elements with indexes i&(i+1)..i inclusive
    return [0] * (m+1)

def fenwick_increase(tree,i,delta):
    """Increase value of i-th element in tree by delta"""
    while i < len(tree):
        tree[i] += delta
        i |= i + 1

def fenwick_sum(tree,i):
    """Return sum of elements 0..i inclusive in tree"""
    s = 0
    while i >= 0:
        s += tree[i]
        i &= i + 1
        i -= 1
    return s

def find_bigger(A):
    """Produce an array in which each element denotes the number of subsequent elements that are bigger"""
    top = max(A) + 1
    F = fenwick_new(top)
    B = []
    for n,a in enumerate(A[::-1]):
        count_of_bigger = n - fenwick_sum(F,a) # n is the number of things we have inserted into the tree so far
        B.append(count_of_bigger)
        fenwick_increase(F,a,1)
    return B[::-1]

A=[2,3,1,5,0,2]
print find_bigger(A)
```

(This algorithm sketch will only work if your input consists of non-negative integers with a reasonable upper bound.  If you have a more complicated input, first compute the rank of each input element using a sort function.)

Comment: Thanks for the algorithm sketch. I am not familiar with Fenwick tree, guess I need to study that first. But yes, in my original problem, the inputs can be negative as well. I will try to implement the algorithm in Java with your ranking suggestion.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your explanation for this code ?